# MySQL reusing a value returned by a function

Tags: mysql

I use a function that returns the difference between the stored time and NOW()

Example:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), `stored_time`)
```

If I'm going to use the returned value in a single query, such as this:

```
SELECT `column1`, `column2` TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), `stored_time`)
FROM `table`
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), `stored_time`) > 2
```

Is there a way to reuse the value? I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT `column1`, `column2` @timediff = TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), `stored_time`)
FROM `table`
WHERE @timediff > 2
```

But it doesn't work. I know nothing about MySQL variables. How do I solve this?

Comment: `SELECT column1, column2, @timediff := TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), stored_time)` (comma and colon added). SQL standard indeed requires the repetition of the column expression in the where condition. Or a different construct.

Comment: So, there is no way that I can do what I want to achieve? I'm cool with that. I just want to know if I can do it more efficiently :D

Comment: Common sub-expressions will be done intelligently.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```
SELECT tt.`column1`, tt.`column2`, t.timediff
FROM `table` tt
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), tt.`stored_time`) as timediff) t on 1=1
WHERE t.timediff > 2
```

(this wasn't tested, but might put you on the right track if this is what you're looking for)

The above apparently wouldn't work with MySQL (which makes sense... I was thinking more along the lines of an `APPLY`/`LATERAL JOIN` style query, which doesn't exist in MySQL). So, another thing that you might want to try is this:

```
SELECT tt.`column1`, tt.`column2`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t.dtnow, tt.`stored_time`)
FROM `table` tt
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT NOW() as dtnow) t on 1=1
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t.dtnow, tt.`stored_time`) > 2
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.timediff FROM table tt

Comment: @userx01 Did you use my exact query, or change something? If its different, can you please post the exact version you ran?

Comment: I don't think you can access `table.stored_time` in the `LEFT JOIN` clause. Something like this would be valid in SQL Server though.

Comment: I think I've found a solution to my problem. All I have to do is give an alias to TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), `stored_time`). But, if I use an alias, I'm not sure if the function will still be called twice. And quoting @Joop Eggen, "common sub-expressions will be done intelligently"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to assign it the function value, *but* you have to initialize the variable in the `WHERE` clause, *then* use it in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT `column1`, `column2`, @timediff
FROM `table`
WHERE (@timediff:= TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `stored_time`, NOW())) > 2
```

As as side-note, if you want `TIMESTAMPDIFF` to return a *positive* value, then you have to pass the most recent date as the 3rd argument.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ae07/1)

Comment: This is weird. It is working on SQL Fiddle, but not on phpmyadmin. I used the exact same values. O_o

Comment: @userx01 Are you passing `NOW()` as the 3rd argument in `TIMESTAMPDIFF` ?

Comment: I am passing it as the second argument. Because what I want is `stored_time` - now.

Comment: @userx01 So, `stored_time` is some date in the future?